# Changing Combobox/Table Item textcolor on Mouseover in ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox, resourcedictionary

I am using `MahAppsMetro` and therefore I have a `ResourceDictionary` where I can change the color of the design.
Now I changed the color to blue. But I do not know how to change the `textcolor` of an `selected item` in an `combobox` / `table`.
It looks like this now:

[Example: Combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWAOG.png)

[Example: Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ5ZY.png)

So now I want to change the Textcolor to white by the ResourceDictionary..
It looks something like this yet:

```
<!-- re-set brushes too -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush" Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" options:Freeze="True" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" options:Freeze="True" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush2" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor2}" options:Freeze="True" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush3" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor3}" options:Freeze="True" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush4" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor4}" options:Freeze="True" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowTitleColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" options:Freeze="True" />

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBrush" EndPoint="0.001,0.5" StartPoint="1.002,0.5" options:Freeze="True">
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource AccentColor3}" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckmarkFill" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" options:Freeze="True" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RightArrowFill" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" options:Freeze="True" />
```

Can you tell me what I need to add to my ResourceDictionary to have a white text on MouseOver of the items.

Hope it is clear what I want to do. Else please tell me what further information you need.

**edit:**

For the `Combobox` is it working now. But not for the `DataGrid`.
Here is how I added the `DataGrid`:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="mydatagrid" SelectionUnit="FullRow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="159,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="204" Width="275" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Transparent" CanUserAddRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" BorderThickness="0" CanUserResizeRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="User" Binding="{Binding User, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vote" Binding="{Binding Vote, Mode=OneWay}" Width="90" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False"  />
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="66" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Status, Mode=OneWay}" Width="16"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Real_Username" Binding="{Binding Real_Username, Mode=OneWay}" Width="90" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

I tried to add different methods to my Application.xaml and expanded the triggers of IsMouseOver with:

```
<Setter Property="Controls.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource AccentSelectedColorBrush}" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never tried it myself but i would suggest looking at triggers see: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible, but for the MouseOver you need to override MahApps ComboBoxItem and  extend it with a Trigger. The SelectedItem uses the ColorBrush: AccentSelectedColorBrush.
Here is the original MetroComboBoxItem extended with a Trigger for MouseOver

app.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
    <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentSelectedColorBrush" Color="DeepPink" />
  <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" x:Key="MetroComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentWhiteBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0,0.5">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverRectangle">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1"
                                                              Value=".65" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                              Value=".55" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedRectangle">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1"
                                                              Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard />
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedRectangle"
                               IsHitTestVisible="False"
                               Opacity="0"
                               Fill="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverRectangle"
                               IsHitTestVisible="False"
                               Opacity="0"
                               Fill="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush3}" />
                    <ContentControl Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
                    </ContentControl>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement"
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource HighlightBrush}"
                               StrokeThickness="1"
                               Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource AccentSelectedColorBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <!-- This Trigger is new -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource AccentSelectedColorBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
     </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just searched for the part of the code you provided and found it when I opened the dll with ILSpy.
So therefore I think I found the right point where to do the changes.
Unfortunately I am not aware about how to change it.. With ILSpy I am only able to read it. Can you or someone explain me how to change this part in the .dll file ?
Or am I wrong with what I want to do?

Comment: why don't you add the code snippet upon to your Window.Resources? Then it is done. Changing the dll is not necessary. Second option would be to change the sources (download sources from MahApps at GitHub https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro and change the Controls.ComboBox.xaml) directly (you could append the style with trigger) and compile your own MahApps.dll

Comment: I have more than one window and I use several comboboxes. Therefore I want to change it only on one point for all comboboxes.
Thats why I'd prefer the second option. I already downloaded the sources, opened it in Visual Studio and found the right place to add my change - but it shows the error "The name "TextBoxHelper" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls"". Therefore I am not able to compile my own dll.. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you could add the code snippet in your app.xaml, beyond the place where you load the resourcedictionarys from MahApps. and everything is done without recompiling. If you want to recompile the project you should load the latest release sources (not the develop branch...). Then compiling should work.

Comment: I had to change the way how I use the style sheets. Now it is working as expected with your code snippet. But is it possible to only add the part with only the Setter Part for the mouse over?
Because when I shorten the code to the part I actually just want to add then the combobox shows no more items eventhough they are actually there.

Comment: thats the problem, you can't only add the Trigger, because it is used inside the controls template. You only have access to this point from template itself and have to rewrite it.

Comment: Okay - thank you.
I have just tried to do the same thing for the DataGrid - but I am not sure what I am doing wrong this time. I took the Style Part from the sourcecode where x:Key = "MetroDataGridRow" and added a Foreground Setter to the  IsMouseOver trigger. Foreground stays black.
Any idea why?

Comment: Foreground could be overwritten by DataGridCell. Try to set it there...

Comment: I tried it. First only by DataGridCell and then both (DataGridCell and DataGridRow) but nothing happens

Comment: just edited my quesiton - maybe you have another idea

Comment: Added this in a new answer. Please don't forget to `upvote` correct answers!

Answer (score 0):

For DataGrid it is easy:

if you like to style whole Line cells, `OnMouseOver` or `IsSelected` use this:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- Full Row -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DeepPink" />
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Cells only this:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- Cell only -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DeepPink" />
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You can place the `Style` in your app.xaml to work for your whole application.

Comment: I think that I wanted to make it to complicated. Your solution works very fine for me. Thank you! But there is one more question I have - is it possible to reduce the opacity for this row? So that it is a bit lighter then the one that is selected?
I just tried to use the code-snippet from the other answer where the opacity is reduced but that did not work...

Comment: See the updated answer. and don't forget to upvote the answers!

Comment: Well - is it also possible to just change Opacity for the background? Now it changes for the whole row (Fore- and Backrgound)

And another problem: I have different Style.xaml files where i set the different colors. On runtime I can change them and replace them in the application.xaml but when I do this the value of the Foregroundcolor won't update - it always stays in like it was defined in the xaml file that loads first..

Comment: And I upvote the answers but as I have under 15 reputations my votes are not visible :)

Comment: Fixed the Problem "Opacity only for the background" by adding opacity in the xaml file that I am binding.
Problem that Forground Color stays as it has been defined in the xaml file that loads first is still there..

Comment: I am now faceing following problem:
I have some tabitems. When I select a row in the ´DataGrid´ Foregroundcolor is white - when I switch the tabitem and go back to my tab the Foregroundcolor change(s/d) black. That makes it hard to read on a dark background...